# PHP header location with tab in html

Tags: php

how can i locate the page and makes active the certain tab

here's my php

```
header('location: home.php?id=tab2');
```

and my html : tab

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="navtabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#aaa">Apply Now!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbb">Announcements</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="tab3" data-toggle="tab" href="#ccc">Examination Schedule</a>
    </li>
```

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="aaa" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                  Tab 1
    </div>

    <div id="bbb" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>

                This is Tab 2   
    </div>

    <div id="ccc" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                Tab 3
    </div>
```

i want to locate my php function with already active the certain tab

Comment: Just have each tab check if the `activeid` matches its id. If so, give it the class of `active`

Comment: You could also try `header('location: home.php?id=#tab2');` to see if it works.

Comment: @JeanPaul98 doesn't work

Comment: Looking at your redirect, it's redirecting the page to focus on the link that has that ID rather than the tab, shouldn't you make it so that it focuses on the tab rather than the link ID? I didn't see it at first but you should try `header('location: home.php#aaa');` or `header('location: home.php#bbb');`

Comment: I have the same problem...is anyone has a solution for this???

Comment: @Del did you found the solution??

Answer (score 0):

You can easily receive the value of the `id` parameter:

```
$tab_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Then check if each nav-link has the needed `$tab_id`:

```
<a class="nav-link <?php $tab_id === 'tab1' ? 'active' : '' ?>" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#aaa">Apply Now!</a>
```

The same for tab contents:

```
<div id="aaa" class="container tab-pane <?php $tab_id === 'tab1' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><br>
   Tab 1
</div>
```

I hope it will help to resolve your problem.